# What does "cannot convert float[4][4] to float on assignment" mean?

Tags: c++

This is the code that's causing trouble:

```
Mat4::Mat4( float a, float b, float c, float d, float e, float f, float g, float h,            
            float i, float j, float k, float l, float n, float o, float p, float q )
{
m[0][0] = a;
m[0][1] = b;
m[0][2] = c;
m[0][3] = d;
m[1][0] = e;
m[1][1] = f;
m[1][2] = g;
m[1][3] = h;
m[2][0] = i;
m[2][1] = j;
m[2][2] = k;
m[2][3] = l;
m[3][0] = m;
m[3][1] = n;
m[3][2] = o;
m[3][3] = p;
}
```

It would seem it's a simple constructor, but clearly it has issues with it.  The goal here is to take every one of those floats and put it into the 2d array I have created there.  I have also tried doing this->m[][] but that doesn't work either.

I'm sure it's something silly I'm overlooking but I cannot figure it out for the life of me.

Comment: `m[3][0] = m;` - think about it.

Comment: Piggybacking on @R.MartinhoFernandes, notice you have cleverly *skipped* `m` in your list of parameters...

Comment: OMFG clearly.  How did I not see that?!  I'm such an idiot!

Comment: Now that you saw it, can I suggest naming your parameters like `m00`, `m01`, ... or something similar?

Comment: yes, actually it was a project I was working on for someone else. This other person is clearly not heard about good naming conventions :).  Though now I have this doozy of a problem, I don't even know where to start with this.

/tmp/cc3mR2gP.o: In function `main':
debug.cpp:(.text+0x1a7): undefined reference to `Vec3::Vec3(float, float, float)'

Comment: That's poor coding style. The parameter names don't mean anything, and there are too many of them. Give the function one parameter. An array of size 16 would do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's something silly: you're using "m" as the name of an array (presumably a member array) Doh! ;)

Comment: Any ideas what:

/tmp/cc3mR2gP.o: In function main': debug.cpp:(.text+0x1a7): undefined reference to Vec3::Vec3(float, float, float)' 

means?  I have the vec3.h file included as it should be, so I'm lost.

Comment: It sounds like you declared the type (class "Vec3", with constructor "Vec3::Vec3(float, float, float)"), but you never actually implemented that constructor (presumably in a file called "vec3.cpp").